# problem for using jquery update module

Tags: 7, commerce, javascript

Right now, I am using [JQUERY UPDATE](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module, 7.X-3.0-alpha2 version. The default version is 2.1. However, I have some trouble when I edit my product which is a reference field.

If I enable this module, when I try to edit my product, I will receive some AJAX error message.

[image]

If I disable this module, I cannot even add an existing product to content type. After I click the "add existing product" button, nothing will happen.
[image]

**Edit**:
**My default version is 1.8 now, but still doesn't work. I also tried 1.7 version.**

[image]

Also got this error:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. after I configure the module, do I need to clear the cache or do some other thing?
2. According to my new edit, is that the correct place to change the jQuery version?

**Note**: It used to work before. There is no new error in console. But I got some "GET XXXX net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Comment: Try using older jQuery version instead 2.1 try 1.10, 1.8 and so on. You can change the version when you configure the module.

Comment: I edit my question. I tried 1.7 and 1.8 version, but doesn't work. I have two questions: 1. after I configure the module, do I need to clear the cache or do some other thing? 2. According to my new edit, is that the correct place to change the jQuery version?

Comment: Any error message display in console?

Comment: It used to work before. There is no new error in console.

Comment: 2) No, you need to go to `/admin/config/development/jquery_update` and change the jquery for **Alternate jQuery version for administrative pages** and 1) yes, you need to clear the cache.

Comment: @jmu : please delete your comments which are now included in your question (and further edit your question if you don't like the way I integrated them).

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I just reboot my server and everything works fine.